# Compiler error on pointer to stdio FILE

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

The android NDK is complaining about this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fileno (FILE *stream); //line 27 io.h
```

It says:

```
jni/application/io.h:27:5: error: expected ')' before '*' token
jni/application/io.h:27:5: error: expected ')' before '->' token
```

I would understand if `FILE` was some macro, but it's not, it's just the one from stdio.

If I take out the `*stream` I get:

```
int fileno (FILE);
jni/application/io.h:27:5: error: expected ')' before '->' token
```

I can't understand where it's getting the `->` token from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait I see, `fileno` is macro in `stdio.h`

So was expanding to:

```
int ((FILE* stream)->_file);
```